# How can I show this inequality by differentiation?

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

Given that $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{s}=1,r>1, s>1$ and $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are positive real numbers.

By differentiating $f(x)=\mu_1x+\mu_2(1-x^s)^\frac{1}{s}$, show that $\forall x \in (0,1)$

$$\mu_1x+\mu_2(1-x^s)^\frac{1}{s} \le (\mu_1^r+\mu_2^r)^\frac{1}{r} $$

**My attempt:**

It is not difficult to find that

$$f'(x)=\mu_1+\mu_2\frac{1}{s}(1-x^s)^{\frac{1}{s}-1}(-sx^{s-1})$$

And solve $f'(x)=0$ to give

$$x=\frac{\mu_1^r}{\mu_1^r+\mu_2^r}$$

and find that it is a maximum point by simple testing.

So we get $$f(x) \le f(\frac{\mu_1^r}{\mu_1^r+\mu_2^r})$$

Then how can I proceed?

Comment: how have you solved $$f'(x)=0$$?

Answer (score 0):

solving your equation $$f'(x)=0$$ we get
$$\frac{\mu_1^{s/(s-1)}}{\mu_2^{s/(s-1)}}=\frac{x^s}{1-x^s}$$
with $$A=\mu_1^{s/(s-1)}$$ and $$B=\mu_2^{s/(s-1)}$$
we get
$$A=x^s(A+B)$$
therefore
$$x=\left(\frac{A}{A+B}\right)^{1/s}$$